# What explains the performance difference in Dask between DataFrame.assign(**kwargs) and dd[x]=y when appending multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

While migrating some code from Pandas to Dask I found an enormous performance difference between modifying a Dask dataframe by calling `DataFrame.assign()` with multiple columns vs modifying it with multiple `DataFrame.__setitem__()` (aka `dataframe[x]=y`) calls.

With imports

```
import pandas, dask, cProfile
```

For a Dask dataframe defined as:

```
dd = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1]}), npartitions=1)
```

```
cProfile.run('for i in range(100): dd["c"+str(i)]=dd["a"]+i')
```

takes 1.436 seconds

while

```
cProfile.run('dd.assign(**{"c"+str(i):dd["a"]+i for i in range(100)})')
```

only takes 0.211 seconds. A 6.8X difference.

I have already tried looking at the stats with `pyprof2calltree` but couldn't make sense of it.

What explains this difference? And more importantly, is there any way to get the `assign` performance without having to refactor code that is using dd[x]=y repeatedly?

This may not matter or happen for large datasets, I haven't checked, but it does for a single row (why I care about Dask being fast for single rows is a separate topic).

For context, there is a difference in Pandas too but it is a lot smaller:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1]})
```

```
cProfile.run('for i in range (100): df["c"+str(i)]=df["a"]+i')
```

takes 0.116 seconds.

```
cProfile.run('df.assign(**{"c"+str(i):df["a"]+i for i in range(100)})')
```

takes 0.096 seconds. Just 1.2X.

Comment: looping vs vectorizing, have a look here perhaps: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Answer (score 0):

Two main reasons:

1. The for loop generates a larger task graph (one new layer per item in the loop), compared to the single additional task from the `assign`.
2. `DataFrame.__setitem__` is actually implemented in terms of assign: https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/366c7998398bc778c4aa5f4b6bb22c25b584fbc1/dask/dataframe/core.py#L3424-L3432, so you end up calling the same code, just many more times. Each assign is associated with a copy in pandas.

> I have already tried looking at the stats with pyprof2calltree but couldn't make sense of it.

Profilers like this (built on cProfile) aren't well suited for profiling parallel code like Dask.

Comment: I see, thanks! i did profile using the single threaded scheduler and saw the assign calls but I missed the fact that the pandas df is copied. I am curious as to why that's then behavior rather than doing it in place (mimicking pandas), but I probably just don't understand how Dask works.